# Will send() ever block when using select()?

Tags: c, sockets, select

When a socket is signalled as being OK to write by a call to `select()`, how can I know how much data I can send without blocking? (In the case of full send buffers etc.)

Does inclusion in the set returned by `select()` signify that the socket is ready for at least one byte of data, and will `send()` then return a short count of written bytes?

Or will it block when I call `send()` with a `len` parameter that is bigger than the available buffer space? If so, how do I know the maximum amount?

I'm using regular C sockets on Linux.

Comment: If your API supports it you can use the `SO_SNDLOWAT` option. That way  you can choose a minimum number of bytes that need to be writable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `send` call should not block on the first call, and should send at least one byte on the first call -- assuming you are using a stream protocol and assuming it's not interrupted by a signal, etc.  However, there are really only two ways to figure out how much data you can send:

1. Call `select` after every call to `send` to see if more data can be sent.
2. Put the socket in non-blocking mode, and call `send` until it gives an `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` error.

The second option is preferred.  (The third option is to do it in a different thread and simply let the thread block, which is also a good solution.  In the past, threading implementations weren't as mature so non-blocking mode was seen as necessary for high-performance servers.)

Comment: +1 for second option, which also happens to be very common practice.

Comment: Why is 2 preferred? I think an explanation or reference would improve this answer a lot. Also, can't you do both?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot know. You have to sent the socket to be non-blocking, and then pay attention to the return value that tells you how much it has written.